# RewriteRule htaccess changes URL

Tags: .htaccess

I want to make some "friendly" urls with htaccess. On localhost all works fine, but when I upload the same files in an hosting, the urls are not as written in htaccess.

Codes:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /c.php?c=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/page/([0-9]+)$ /c.php?c=$1&p=$2 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ /a.php?a=$2 [L]
```

On localhost, the links are corrected, they are like "localhost/word/page/2", but in my site they are "mysite.com/c.php?c=word&p=2". I tried with R=302, R=301, but nothing. Options +FollowSymlinks not works, giving me a "500 error".

**EDIT: Resolved with Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch !**